# How to provide data to Animated time-line pie amcharts?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, amcharts

I am trying to push data dynamically during runtime for the [Animated Time-Line Pie Chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animated-time-line-pie-chart/)

Here is the code:

```
var array = new Array();
function pushvalue(curyear,curmonth,monvalue){
        array.push({year: curyear, month: curmonth, count: moncount});
}
var chartdata = new Array();
for (var i=1; i < array.length; i++){
     chartdata = {
             “Year”: array[i].year: [
                          { “Month”: array[i].month, “Count”: array[i].count }, ] };
}
```

The value for array is got from input from file.
The problem I get is the chartdata can’t get the value assigned to it with the objects year, it shows error as expected a ‘}’ or syntax error if I include or exclude ‘:’ after the `”Year”: array[i].year`

May I know what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for assigning a new year is wrong. You can't do "Year": varname: [ ... ] in one line. You'll want to change it to something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  if (!chartData[array[i].year]) {
    chartData[array[i].year] = [];
  }
  chartData[array[i].year].push({"Month": array[i].month, "Count": array[i].count });
}
```

Demo using some fake values: http://jsfiddle.net/9428r6fw/4/

Also note that your `pushvalue` method is wrong - your parameter for the count is named `monvalue` but you're trying to push `moncount`

Comment: This works, thank you so much @xorspark. Yeah I noticed the pushvalue method argument were mismatched, it was a typo.