# How to provide multiple valuefields to Animated amcharts timeline pie chart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to display more than one values in the balloontext of the [Animated Time-Line Pie Chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animated-time-line-pie-chart/)

Here is the code:

```
function pushvalue(curyear,curmonth,monvalue,state,statecount){
array.push({year: curyear, month: curmonth, count: monvalue, state: state, statecount: statecount});
}

var monthNames = ["January", "February","March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December”];
var currentYear = 1997;
var array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
for (var j = 0; j < 12; ++j) {
pushvalue(currentYear + i, monthNames[j],count[j],state[j],statecount[j]);
}
}

var chartData = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  if (!chartData[array[i].year]) {
    chartData[array[i].year] = [];
  }
  chartData[array[i].year].push({"Month": array[i].month, "Count": array[i].count, “State”: array[i].state, “StateCount”: array[i].statecount });
}

var currentYear = 1997;
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [],
  "valueField": "Count",
  “valueField1”: “State”,
  “valueField2”: “StateCount”,
  "titleField": "Month",
  "startDuration": 0,
  "innerRadius": 80,
  "pullOutRadius": 20,
  "marginTop": 30,
“balloonText”: “Completed [[value2]] for [[value1]] states in [[title]] month”,
“labelText”: “[[title]] - [[value]]”,
  "titles": [{
    "text": "Test chart"
  }],
  "allLabels": [{
    "y": "54%",
    "align": "center",
    "size": 25,
    "bold": true,
    "text": "1995",
    "color": "#555"
  }, {
    "y": "49%",
    "align": "center",
    "size": 15,
    "text": "Year",
    "color": "#555"
  }],
  "listeners": [ {
    "event": "init",
    "method": function( e ) {
      var chart = e.chart;

  function getCurrentData() {
    var data = chartData[currentYear];
    currentYear++;
    if (currentYear > 2000)
      currentYear = 1997;
    return data;
  }

  function loop() {
    chart.allLabels[0].text = currentYear;
    var data = getCurrentData();
    chart.animateData( data, {
      duration: 1000,
      complete: function() {
        setTimeout( loop, 3000 );
      }
    } );
  }

  loop();
}
  } ],
    } );
```

I want the valueField, valueField1 & valueField2 to be displayed in the balloonText and labelText while the pie chart loads.

But the chart appears blank while loading as it’s not reading valueField1 & valueField2.
I understand I am doing some mistake while assigning valueField1 & valueField2.
Can someone help me fix it and 
May I know how to make the chart display values in chartData.state and chartData.statecount?

Thank you!

PS this is a continuation for [How to provide data to Animated time-line pie amcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46475345/7115396)
Values assigned in

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
for (var j = 0; j < 12; ++j) {
pushvalue(currentYear + i,monthNames[j],count[j],state[j],statecount[j]);
}
}
```

Are not actual prod code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set multiple valueFields in a pie chart, but you can reference the fields by name through `[[shortcodes]]`, i.e. `[[State]]` and `[[StateCount]]` as indicated in the [`balloonText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#balloonText) and [`labelText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#labelText) documentation (emphasis mine):

> The following tags can be used: [[value]], [[title]], [[percents]], [[description]] ***or any other field name from your data provider.***

Your `balloonText` should look like this:

`"balloonText": "Completed [[State]] for [[StateCount]] states in [[title]] month",`

Adjust your labelText accordingly.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9428r6fw/5/)

Comment: I never know that amchart accepts the short codes in balloonText and labelText. This works perfectly! Thank you so much @xorspark